# A question about input size in a tensorflow neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm a PyTorch user but recently reading some code implemented using tensorflow.
My question is, if we just have a simple neural network like this, where is the **input** size specified? Or is this model allowed to work with a *variable* size input?

```
class SimpleNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleNet, self).__init__()
        activation = tf.keras.activations.tanh
        self.features = [

         #Where is the input size specified?
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(89, activation),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(6 * 32, activation),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
        ]

    def process(self, x):
        x = apply_layers(x, self.features)
        return x

    ...
```

Comment: The size cannot be variable here. If the input size is not specified, with a first layer Input() for example, the model initializes its weights the first time it is called, from the shape of the data (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input_shape` is inferred when you pass real data to your model. Meaning, the `input_shape` is variable if you do not explicitly define it.
For example, you could explicitly define your `input_shape` in the first layer of your model:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(89, activation, input_shape=(5,))
```

And each layer derives the required `input shape` from the output of the previous layer. Note, however, that once you feed your model with real data, it stores this `input_shape` for future use. Another example shows that it does not matter what shape the data has as long as it is compatible with the first `Dense` layer:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

activation = tf.keras.activations.tanh
model1 = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(89, activation),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6 * 32, activation),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    ])

tf.print('Works -->', model1(tf.random.normal((10, 1))).shape)
model2 = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(89, activation),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6 * 32, activation),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    ])
tf.print('Works -->', model2(tf.random.normal((10, 5))).shape)
```

```
Works --> TensorShape([10, 1])
Works --> TensorShape([10, 1])
```

where 10 represents the number of samples and 1 and 5 the number of features.

Comment: Got it, so it is inferred from the first input and then asks for all the other inputs to be the same size.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: @AloneTogether: Thanks for your answer. You wrote "And each layer derives the required input shape from the output of the previous layer." --> But this is only valid for the Dense layer right? For other types of Tensorflow Neural Networks (as it is labelled in the title of the question), it can be different. For example for recurrent layers like RNN or LSTM the input size has to be [Batch, Timesequence, Features] as far as I understand.

Comment: Yeah, I am referring to Dense layer in my answer. A RNN or LSTM obviously needs a different input shape.